# How to solve Execution failed for task transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Debug on Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

When i try build a APK width Cordova, this show me a error exception.
To create my APK i use
`cordova build android`
Before install Windows 10, i use the same configuration, but work well.

**My steps**

- Create project with `cordova create Example com.example.app Example`
- Add platform support with `cordova platform add android`
- Add plugins support with `cordova plugin add XYZ`
- prepare cordova project with `cordova prepare android`
- build cordova APK with `cordova build android` (***i don't use --release 'cos i need debug APK***)

**My configuration:**

- Windows 10 x64 width 16GB Ram and AMD 2.4 Ghz * 8 Core( ***I don't use Emulator 'cos is too slow in AMD***)
- Cordova **6.1.1**
- Java **1.8.0_91**
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
- Android Studio **2.1** (Build AI-143.2790544)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
- PATH: **ANDROID_HOME**=C:\Users\Olaf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- PATH: **JAVA_HOME**=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_91

**build.gradle file**

```
// GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!

apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
   }

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.8'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/app-xwalk.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode") + "0")
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
      def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
      // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
      // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
      // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
      if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
      } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
        defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
      }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

**My Plugins:**

- cordova-android-support-v4 4.0.0 "Android Support v4"
- cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.7.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
- cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-file 4.2.0 "File"
- cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.2.0 "Geolocation"
- cordova-plugin-media 2.3.0 "Media"
- cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
- cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.0.12 "SocialSharing"
- SDK Packages(**all**) [image: SDK Packages]
- SDK Tools(**all**)[image: SDK Tools]
- SDK Updates(**all**)[image: SDK Updates]

**The output error:**

```
C:\Users\Olaf\Desktop\Projects\Example>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Olaf\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_91
null
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preArmv7DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkArmv7DebugManifest
:preX86DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preArmv7ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preX86ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Alpha2Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareOrgXwalkXwalk_core_library_beta184847713Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareArmv7DebugDependencies
:compileArmv7DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileArmv7DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateArmv7DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeArmv7DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:createXwalkCommandLineFileArmv7Debug
:generateArmv7DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processArmv7DebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processArmv7DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateArmv7DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileArmv7DebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileArmv7DebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Debug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


 FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 24.646 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForArmv7Debug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\Olaf\Desktop\Projects\Example\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Olaf\Desktop\Projects\Example\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Please, if you know the solution, tell me to continue with my projecto, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after few days of learning about this problem, I found a solution.
In my case, the solution was too simple because I only needed to remove `android-support-v4.jar` from `platforms/android/libs` in my Cordova project.

So, if you create a `Cordova/Phonegap/Ionic` project, you have the tree like to

```
ExampleProject/
    - hooks/
    - platforms/
        - android
            - ...
            - libs/
                - android-support-v4.jar <--- REMOVE!!
            - ...
    - plugins/
        - ...
    - www/
        - ...
```

If you can't find the `android-support-v4.jar` in the `libs` folder, you can find it in your `plugins` folder like this:

```
ExampleProject/
    - hooks/
    - platforms/
        - ...
    - plugins/
        - cordova-android-support-v4/
                - android-support-v4.jar <--- REMOVE!!
    - www/
        - ...
```

> Remember reload project with the command `cordova prepare <platform>`,
>   where `<platform>` is you platform like `ios`, `android`, `windows` ,
>   `firefox`, etc.
>
> In case of Phonegap you can use `phonegap prepare <platform>`.
>
> In case of Ionic you can use `ionic prepare <platform>`.

Bye!

Comment: I have the same issue as you, but I do not have the .jar file mentioned. Did you change anything else in your attempts to fix it?

Comment: i use cordova 6.1.1, maybe if u use the same version can u fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe u can find the jar file if u search on plugins folder. If u can see "cordova-android-support-v4" on plugins folder, enter in it, can delete `android-support-v4.jar`. Remember, the plugin folder is on `$ MyCordovaProject/plugins/`.
Tell me if this answer help u. bye n' good luck!

Comment: not finding android-support-v4.jar too. Using cordova 6.3.0, what should I do?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by reseting all of the cordova plugins:

`ionic state reset -- plugins`

And then adding and removing the platforms

`cordova platform remove android`, `cordova platform add android`

Comment: Thanks men, i was crazy for solved that problem, i apply many solutions, but don't work for me, thanks.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but many plugins did not get installed after removing and adding platform.

Comment: Please check your package.json file, all of your plugins should be listed there, in the *cordova -> plugins* object.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted in config.xml build the version of android and it's built successfully

Comment: what you deleted in config.xml

Answer (score 2):

fix for me updating to android@6.2

```
cordova platform add android@6.2
```